# create relation between two tables

Tags: c#, dao

I am trying to create a relationship between two tables.
User choose the first table (choice1) then choose the second table (choice2) and choose the field in the second table (field2). He then gives a name to the relationship (namerelationship)

I get this error

> Invalid field definition 'ForeignKey' in definition of index or relationship

```
string namerelationship = txtNameRelationship.Text;
string choice1 = cboTable1.SelectedItem.ToString();
string choice2 = cboTable2.SelectedItem.ToString();
string field2 = cboField2.SelectedItem.ToString();

Relation myrel = clsDataSource.mydb.CreateRelation(namerelationship,  choice1, choice2);
Field myfield = new Field();
myfield = myrel.CreateField(choice1);
myfield.ForeignName = "ForeignKey";
myrel.Fields.Append(myfield);
clsDataSource.mydb.Relations.Append(myrel);
```

Comment: Could you explain what problems are you experiencing with the above code?

Comment: I updated it with my error

Comment: why don't you do a google search on the following `C# DataSource.CreateRelation` it appears that you are doing this incorrectly currently

Comment: You have tagged this question with DAO that is a lot older than ADO. Which library are you using?

Comment: I am using DAO for this project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the Relation object of DAO you need to specify for the first field the name of an existing field from the first table (usually this is the primary key) and for the ForeignName property the name of a field of the second table that act as ForeignKey to the first table.

So suppose you have a Deparment table with

```
IDDepartment (integer, primary key)
Description (text, not null)
```

And a table Employee

```
IDEmployee (integer, primary key)
Name (text not null)
IDDepartment (integer, foreign key to Department table)
```

where a relationship exists between the Department and the Employee table of this kind: An employee work in one (and only one) department. (1 to 1)

Then your code should be

```
string choice1 = "Department";
string choice2 = "Employee";
string fieldPK = "IDDepartment"; // It is the primary key of Department
string fieldFK = "IDDepartment"; // It is the foreign key in table Employee that links to the Department table
Relation myrel = clsDataSource.mydb.CreateRelation(namerelationship,  
                 choice1, choice2);
Field myfield = myrel.CreateField(fieldPK);
myfield.ForeignName = fieldFK;
myrel.Fields.Append(myfield);
clsDataSource.mydb.Relations.Append(myrel);
```

Said that I really recommend you to switch as soon as possible from DAO to ADO.NET

Comment: Thank you. Following your explanation and making my variables more clear I succeeded to create relationships.